# How to run pyasn1 installed with pip

Tags: python, pyasn1

Apparently I'm doing something wrong, and all instructions I have found literally everywhere say how to install (program name here) with PIP but not how to execute it.

I am trying to run pyasn1, using a python3 virtual environment.

I have also tried using my default python2.7 environment, but no love there, either.

```
python3 -m venv asn1_env
source asn1_env/bin/activate
```

Just to check that I'm in the new virtual environment.

```
which python
/Users/xxxx/asn1_env/bin/python
```

Now we install pyasn1 for the umpteenth time...

```
pip install pyasn1
Successfully installed pyasn1-0.4.5
```

This is where things go awry...

```
which pyasn1
```

(nothing, can't find it in the virtual path)

```
find . -name "pyasn1.*"

./asn1_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyasn1
```

(only finds a directory, which contains a bunch of files, none of which are called pyasn1)

Obviously, this won't work, either...

```
python pyasn1.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'pyasn1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you try `import pyasn1` in the python REPL? I'm new to pyasn1 - but it looks like a library - which doesn't export an executable. So I wouldn't expect `pyasn1` to be a command in the shell after installation. But if you open up a python shell and type in `import pyasn1` it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to run in `pyasn1` because it's a library, not a runnable program.

The intended workflow is that you fist express your ASN.1 data structures in form of `pyasn1` classes, then you could either decode serialized data (BER/DER/CER) into Python objects or vice-versa.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't at all clear from the documentation in the Readme.md. That would explain why there weren't any examples on how to run it from the command line. (or perhaps I need to improve my reading comprehension. )